# How to solve delayed display issue after removing a comment in React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, event-listener

I'm developing a React application that allows users to view and remove comments on a page. The issue I'm facing is that when a user removes a comment, the page display doesn't update in real-time to reflect the removed comment. However, when I refresh the page, the removed comment is no longer displayed. I've tried adding a state that updates after the comment is removed, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I solve this issue and ensure that the page display updates immediately after a comment is removed? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
CHILD COMPONENT

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const DeleteComment = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {
        const id = searchParams.get("id");
        getDataArticle(parseInt(id));
    }, [searchParams]);

    const getDataArticle = async (id) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/articles?id=${id}`);
            if (!res.ok) {
                console.error("Failed to fetch data");
                return;
            }
            const data = await res.json();
            setData(data[0]);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data", error);
        }
    };

    const deleteElement = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/articles/${data.id}`, {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    ...data,
                    comment: data.comment.filter((element) => element.name !== selected),
                }),
            });
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error("Failed to delete element");
            }
            const newData = {
                ...data,
                comment: data.comment.filter((element) => element.name !== selected),
            };
            setData(newData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error deleting element", error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            deleteElement();
        });
    }, []);




    return (
        <div className="p-5">
            <div className="flex flex-col">
                <div className="flex flex-col">
                    <label className="text-sm font-bold text-gray-700 tracking-wide">
                        Select Comment
                    </label>
                    <select
                        className="block w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-gray-500"
                        onChange={(e) => setSelected(e.target.value)}
                    >
                        <option value="">select Comment</option>
                        {data?.comment?.map((element) => (
                            <option key={element.id} value={element.name}>
                                {element.name}
                            </option>
                        ))}

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button
                className="px-4 py-2 mt-5 text-white bg-blue-500 rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
                onClick={deleteElement}
            >
                Delete Element
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DeleteComment;
FATHER COMPONENT

import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import ArticleBody from '../Components/Article/ArticleBody';
import ModifyArticle from '../Components/CrudArticles/ModifyArticle';
import DeleteArticle from '../Components/CrudArticles/DeleteArticle';
import CardCommentList from '../Components/Comments/CardCommentList';
import ModifyComment from "../Components/Comments/ModifyComment";
import CreateComment from "../Components/Comments/CreateComment";
import Delete from "../Components/Article/DeleteElementBody";
import DeleteComment from "../Components/Comments/DeleteComment";

const CardSection = (props) => {
  const { style, title } = props;

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <h1 className="  font-bold text-2xl">{title}</h1>
    </div>
  );

};

CardSection.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.object,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};


const ArticleTemplate = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = searchParams.get("id");
    getDataArticle(parseInt(id));
  }, [searchParams]);

  const getDataArticle = async (id) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/articles?id=${id}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    setData(data[0]);
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    const id = searchParams.get("id");
    getDataArticle(parseInt(id));
  }, [searchParams]);







  return (
    (typeof data !== "undefined")
      ? <div>
        <div className='flex justify-between'>
          <div className=' m-4'>
            <Link to="/"><img src='../../images/logo.jpeg' alt='' style={{ height: 40, width: 40, marginTop: 10 }} /></Link>
          </div>
          <ModifyArticle data={data} setData={setData} />

        </div>
        <div>
          {data.image && (
            <img
              className='h-320 w-full'
              src={data.image}
              alt=''
            />
          )}
        </div>
        <CardSection
          title={data.title}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', padding: '20px', borderRadius: '5px' }}
        />
        <Delete />
        <ArticleBody data={data} />
        <p className='font-bold text-2xl p-5'>Commenti</p>
        <CardCommentList data={data} />
        <ModifyComment />
        <CreateComment
        />
        <DeleteComment
        />
        <DeleteArticle />
      </div>
      : null
  )
}

export default ArticleTemplate;
```

I have tried various methods to solve this problem, such as using setInterval, which updates the data every 1000 milliseconds and it works, but it's not the correct method. Therefore, I'm wondering how I can solve the situation.